# How to add class to multiple divs with same class, javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple classes with same class name, for example I have 10 classes that have class name test. I want to add new class, for example active, for each class.

So if I have this:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

multiple times on page. How to add to each class active, so it looks like this

```
<div class="test active"></div>
<div class="test active"></div>
<div class="test active"></div>
<div class="test active"></div>
```

Comment: `$('.test').addClass('active');` http://api.jquery.com/addclass

Comment: @RayonDabre `assClass`, quite classy... :)

Comment: that comment with the $$

Comment: I tried this from beginning and it wasn't working. :( Now it works. I'm sorry for the question, it looks stupid. I had some other issue.

Comment: @snoopy_15, [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/7u7ohumt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass)

```
$(".test").addClass("active")
```